# Best practice to install Windows7 when Linux installed already

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, debian, multi-boot

I have dual boot machine with XP+Debian Squeeze, booting is performed via GRUB2. I'd like to upgrade XP to Win7. I know that XP would overwrite my GRUB with it's bootloader, requiring me to reinstall GRUB2 via LiveCD.
My questions:

- Does Win7 behave the same? Is there a way to avoid this effect?
- Are there any issues specific to Win7 as compared to XP concerning dual-boot in general and GRUB2 in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows 7 will override the GRUB boot-loader. To restore it you need an Linux live USB or CD.

[Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)  re-installs GRUB boot-loader, so it should work with Debian installation too, I think.

Anyway, this question is well known. Google for "your-linux-flavor restore grub windows".

I didn't note any specific issues with Windows 7 in dual-boot. It just works.